# Suitable data structure to save localized settings

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, localization, settings

Here's the scenario. I have a set of settings in an app. For example consider my app as a video player. So there are settings like *allow full screen*, *display subtitles* etc. All these settings have boolean values since you either turn on or off them.

These settings should display inside the app in a table view. And if any of them are activated or when the user taps on them to activate/deactivate, you show it by setting the checkmark accessory view of that cell.

Since I need the settings to be displayed this way and only within the app, I cannot simply use Settings bundles. There's also another catch. I need these settings to be localized.

What I initially thought was to have separate plists for the languages I support.

**Settings_en.plist** (English)

[image]

**Settings_sv.plist** (Swedish)

[image]

Then fetch the plist name depending on the system language and display its values.

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(NSLocalizedString("SETTINGS_PLIST", comment: ""))
```

But this is not ideal because say I'm running in Swedish and I change the Subtitles setting to on. Now i have to update this in both plists. This will quickly become even messier if I add more languages in the future.

Is there a better way to store settings which is easier to save and fetch and also supports localization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer elsewhere. Here are the steps taken to resolve this issue.

1. Instead of multiple plists, create one plist and have the keys in English language.

[image]

2. Then have the localized strings in your string files with the same English keys.

**Localizable.strings (English)**

> FULL_SCREEN = "Full Screen";
>
> SUBTITLES = "Subtitles";

**Localizable.strings (Swedish)**

> FULL_SCREEN = "Helskärm";
>
> SUBTITLES = "Undertexter";

3. In the code when you're displaying the values in a table view, refer to them by that key.

---

```
let setting = settings[indexPath.row] as [String: Bool]
let title = setting.keys.first
cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString(title!, comment: "")
```